# Sorting matrix of data into two columns of data in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, formatting, excel-2007

I am having difficulty sorting this data so I simply have one column of dates, and another column with the corresponding numerical values. I've tried to create a Pivot Table, but cannot find a way to achieve my desired result. I've also tried to custom sort. Lastly, I've tried to create another matrix of data but replace the values with the dates corresponding to the values. I could do it this way and manually move things around to get two columns but it is very time consuming so I imagine there must be a faster way! Thank you.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7awdQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is called unpivot. You could use use the Get & Transform From Table command. This is built-in beginning with Excel 2016 for Windows. Here is more information about that https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/